# Trademark Character translation in MySql

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd, ascii

I have a SQL script file that inserts a few constant values into the database. Some of these values contain the Trademark symbol ®. I have two ways of executing this script. One is from the MySQL Workbench GUI application, the other is by calling a Gradle task that runs the script with:

```
cmd = "cmd /c mysql -u ${user} -p${pwd} -h ${host} -P ${port} ${database} < " + sqlScriptFile
```

The problem isn't with gradle of course... I *think* using the '<' operator in Windows is what's causing this. The **®** symbol shows up as **┬«**. If I run 
`more < data.sql` I get the weird translated characters.

Any ideas on what could cause this?

Comment: You are seeing your character in its original [UTF8 encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ae/index.htm). Whether or not this is a problem depends on your entire workflow. (As the link says, it's a Registered symbol, not "Trademark".)

Comment: It is a problem! Do you know if there's a good way to fix it?

Comment: Where do these characters appear - in your `sqlScriptFile`? The editor you used to write this seems to have saved it as UTF8-encoded. That may be just a default, and a good editor will allow you to save as something else. Check if it allows something like 'plain ASCII', 'Latin1', or 'Windows Encoding'.